# Can I define an instance method that has an additional input variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I'm looking for clarification on whether you can, and whether it's best practice to, define an instance method with an addition input variable(s), e.g.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    def instance_method( variable_1 )
    end
end
```

This would allow me to call:

```
@job.instance_method( @variable_1)
```

Is this an accepted and recommended approach? Or would it be better to define a class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there should be no issue with this. This is how setter methods work. Whether you define a class method or not depends on what you are trying to do: If you are trying to do something related to the instance you should use an instance method, if you are trying to access something common to all objects of the class, then use a class method. Example:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  def car_speed(speed)
     #set speed for this car.
  end

  def self.number_of_cars
     Car.all.count
  end
end


Car.number_of_cars #Returns the number of cars saved in the DB

red_car = Car.new
red_car.car_speed(10) #Makes the red car go 10 MPH
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can define as many input variables as you want. If you want to assign a default value you can also do

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    def instance_method( variable_1 = default_value )
    end
end
```